# Expose javascript logic to a web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest

How to expose a javascript logic which is currently there in a legacy system as a webservice?
Only way to do this is convert javascipt code to a another language right? Im finiding a way of expose the javascript code directly as a webservice because it has thousand of codes. So convert those to a java or other language is a huge effort.

Comment: Can you please clean up your question into something proper? Stream of consciousness does not lend itself to clear questions. Spelling errors do not help either.

Comment: The first sentence you have written is almost incomprehensible, atleast to me. So goes for the other sentences as well. To be clear, a service is exposed by a server; and the idea of service is that what language you have written the code doesn't matter. "expose a javascript logic finally alert some text" - my head spins; can you elaborate?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. i have update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put some sort of wrapper around the JS that can take input and output via HTTP and call the appropriate JS functions.

You could write the entire thing using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or you could use another language which has an interface to a JS engine such as [Perl](https://metacpan.org/module/JavaScript%3a%3aV8) or [Java](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).